# Failed to render and update auto layout status: Failed to launch designable agent because tool was shutting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I'm currently having this error in my app, where I'm unable to work with the storyboard because of the error but the application runs. Maes it hard to design UI. Here are screenshots.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMkNK.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuY73.png)

I've tried updating the podfile multiple times with different codes, still no help.

Comment: Well the error message tells you the problem. Remove the `@IBDesignable` designation everywhere it occurs if you want to use the storyboard.

Comment: @matt I do not have that in my any of my code. It's in my cocoapod 'TextFieldEffects' framework.

Comment: Then if you wish to use the storyboard you must change that pod’s code or remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Force quit Xcode and open the project again and it works. Works on Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem today trying to use an @IBDesignable view from a pod in one of my projects.
The following seemed to work for me:

1 - At the end of your **podfile** add these lines:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
   t.build_configurations.each do |config|

    # to make @IBDesignable work with IB
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] ='$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'
   end
 end
end
```

2 - (Optional) Deleting the derived data helps prompt the rebuild of views in IB on a clean slate

You can find the path by going to XCode -> Preferences -> Locations
[image]

3 - Run `pod install` and build your app.

Hopefully that helps clear your problem :)